# A doubt on a proof of Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a proof of the Second Mean Value Theorem from the lecture note of my professor.

[image][image]

Unfortunately, I found that the line
$$\sum_{j=1}^n g(x_j)(F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})) = g(x_1)F(x_0)+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (g(x_{j+1})-g(x_j))F(x_j)$$
is wrong. I think it should be

$$\sum_{j=1}^n g(x_j)(F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})) = -(g(x_1)F(x_0)+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (g(x_{j+1})-g(x_j))F(x_j))$$

However, it will make the inequalities in the lines after this line invalid.

Would anyone like to point out that whether I am correct or not? Also, if I am correct, how can I modify the proof made by my professor to get the desire result? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually that he should have written

$$\sum_{j=1}^n g(x_j)(F(x_{j-1})-F(x_j)) $$